# Bad Toast rotation

Tags: android, user-interface, rotation, toast

I want to rotate toast using next code:

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This is toast!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
View toastView = toast.getView();
toastView.setRotation(90);
toast.show();
```

But it looks like this in the bottom of the screen:

[image: badly rotated toast]

How can I force toast to look good?

If I set custom values to `toastView`'s `setWidth()` and `setHeight()`, all looks good, but I'm looking for more elegant and common way.

Please, keep in mind, I don't want to redraw `toastView`'s `Canvas` (there is such post on StackOverflow already), I just want to rotate ordinary `Toast`.

Answer (score 0):

Just add:

```
toastView.setElevation(100);
```

[API reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:elevation)